# How is Jquery.event.triggered and element.click related

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, webpack-2

First time asking question, please forgive.

Related tech: Knockout and Jquery version: 1.8.3 (very old project)

Background:

I recently converted our ancient project building from grunt to webpack2. Then found a bug where an ELEMENT.trigger('click.NAMESPACE') triggers a click event on the ELEMENT without .bind('click.NAMESPACE'). The ELEMENT is bond to a click event via Knockout.

Finding:

1.)Grunt version: $.event.triggered = "click" would prevent the ELEMENT.trigger from doing anything because element.click() is prevented.

2.)Webpack2 version: element.click() makes $.event.triggered = null and thus able to trigger the Knockout click event accordingly.

3.) ELEMENT.trigger('click.NAMESPACE') triggers both the ELEMENT's click event and the name-spaced event. That's why the Knockout click event is being called via element.click()

Question:

1.) How is $.event.triggered and element.click related, I am unable to find the element.click() native code online.

2.) Any insight why webpack2 would cause this via the same code.

3.) If you happen to know, can you please tell me how to contact someone working for Jquery? It'd be immensely helpful.

p.s. the bug can easily be fixed if I remove this .trigger event, but the use of .trigger is legacy throughout the whole app. Plus, I don't comprehend how Webpack2, a bundler, can have such effect. It's too dangerous to push this build out without knowing why.